# Insert data to powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Im doing an archive process and I want to insert the results to a CSV file.
The process will looks like,

```
$source_path="D:\backup"
$destination="E:\backup"
$start_datetime=date
copy source target
$end_datetime=date
```

## CSV file looks like

```
Date | Start | end | Source | Destination
```

I want to insert the below data.

```
DATE = today's date.
Start = $start_datetime
end = $end_datetime
Source = $source_path
Destination=$destination
```

I tried some ways to write data into CSV, but I couldn't reach the exact thing.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into psobjects - [Example guide](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/)

For example:

```
[array]$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    DATE = today's date.
    Start = $start_datetime
    end = $end_datetime
    Source = $source_path
    Destination=$destination
}

$myObject | Export-Csv C:\temp\myfile.csv
```

---

**Edit** - I'm not sure how you'll be using `Export-Csv`. So I will give a couple of examples. However, this really goes beyond the scope of just exporting CSVs as asked. I would recommend rewriting it with more detail about the requirements, or breaking it into several questions.

```
foreach($thing in $things){

    # increment array with multiple rows
    [array]$myObject += [pscustomobject]@{
        DATE = today's date.
        Start = $start_datetime
        end = $end_datetime
        Source = $source_path
        Destination=$destination
    }
}

# add data to an existing csv, which has the heading DATEM Start, end, Source, Destination
$myObject | Export-Csv C:\temp\myfile.csv -Append
```

---

```
# if/else logic
if($end_time -gt $somevariable){
    [array]$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{
        DATE = today's date.
        Start = $start_datetime
        end = $end_datetime
        Source = $source_path
        Destination=$destination
    }         
}else{
    [array]$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{
        DATE = someotherdate
        Start = $start_datetime
        end = $end_datetime
        Source = $source_path
        Destination=$destination
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But every execution, this CSV file is replaced with the new data, I want to keep upto date.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add to the csv each time the script is ran? So keep old data and add new data?

Comment: Because, the sync file sometimes < 1GB sometimes > 30GB, so based on the end_time, I can come up with which date synced more data. For this I need to track it. Like wise, one more sync scripts with different Export to CSV i'll prepare

Answer (score 1):

You've provided few specific details and only sparse pseudocode, so it's difficult to tell exactly what you're doing or exactly what you want.  However, if you just want to append a record to a CSV file, Export-Csv has an -Append switch.  You can pipe a custom object to Export-Csv as you go.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    DATE = today's date.
    Start = $start_datetime
    end = $end_datetime
    Source = $source_path
    Destination=$destination
} | Export-Csv -Path $CsvFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it helps